# jquery ui - sortable: get new position of all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI - Sortable on following List:

```
<div class="contentEntries">
<div class="contentEntry">...</div>
<div class="contentEntry">...</div>
<div class="contentEntry">...</div>
<div class="contentEntry">...</div>
</div>
```

In the .contentEntry there is an input field with the position:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Position" name="row[contents][23][position]" value="0">
```

I want that if i drag a element to a new position that I get the new position List of all elemnts.

For example:
On every .contentEntry the input with the position has the value 0. Now wenn i drag any element to a new position I want that all elements get the right order as value. So that the input positon value on the first is 1, on the second 2, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, it was not that hard ;)

```
$(function() {
    $('.contentEntries').sortable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find('.contentEntry').each(function(i, el){
                $(this).find('input.position').val(i+1);
            });
        }
    });

    $('.contentEntries').disableSelection();
});
```

But there is still one problem. The right value is displayed in the website, but in the DOM there is still the old value.
edit: already managed it to work :)